# How to prune d3 tree of 0-value leaves and of the branches that lead to them?

Tags: d3.js

I have created a d3 tree layout for an n-level dataset that contains leaf nodes with value >= 0. Some branches are shorter than others, i.e., not all leaves are at the same level.

I would now like to prune the tree of those hierarchies (leaves and branches) whose sum of leaf values equals 0, and am not sure on how to do that. Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can navigate the tree as a normal tree, then do a [post-order traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Post-order), which visits all nodes in the tree before their parents.

When you visit each node,

- Delete the node if it's a value 0 leaf
- Delete the node if it has no children (clears empty branches after possibly having leaves pruned)

Comment: I was hoping that there'd be some elegant d3 solution for this--the lib is deep. Meanwhile, this will do. Thanks for your answer.